# Make object a mask to mask another specific object

Tags: transparency

[image]

As shown in the picture, I have a sphere, plane and Suzanne. Is there a way to use the plane as a mask, but only to mask the sphere and at the same time **not** mask Suzanne?

Comment: how does your plane is supposed to look in render mode? because if you're talking about a completely transparent plane, it won't mask both parts of Suzanne by definition

Comment: I want the plane to be transparent.

Comment: in Cycles you can do it with the Light Path node > Transparent Depth output, in Eevee you probably need to do it through the Compositor, what render engine are you using?

Comment: You can also use the Holdout node for the plane, but again it would help to know what render engine you're planning to use